# How to normalize database with tree structure

Tags: sql-server

I need some help with SQL structure.
I write articles and want to share them online in my web site, that users could comment on them.

Each article contains name, paragraphs, sections and blocks of content.
You can look at it as a tree: article => paragraphs => sections => blocks of content.
each article has many paragraphs, each paragraph has many sections and each section has many blocks of content.

Now, i would like that users will be able to add their comments for every level in the tree.
In order to do so i created a table for each entity (article, paragraph, sections and blocks of content) that holds static information .

My question is what is the best way to handle the dynamic part, where to store the users' comments?
what is the best solution here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendations it to create a table per each entity that where to store the comments.

So for example you can create the following tables:

- article_comments
- paragraph_comments
- section_comments
- blockscontent_comments

so each table is going to store the parent entity Id, the user ID (If is registered or null if is not registered) and the comment.

The reason why I recommend tou to use different tables instead only one are the following ones:

- It is a scalable solution in the sense that in the future you can add custom fields to each comments table that are only related to the parent entity. If you do that with one table in the future the table structure can become messy with many empty or null row fields.
- Your tables are going to look sorted and structured.
- If in the future you have a big number of comments your RDBMS will take less time querying from different tables instead of one table (And queries become heavies and slower when long text/blobs fields are used).
- It is easy to setup foreign constraints with only one parent table and the referential integrity checks are going to take less time.

Comment: What about performance? i'll have to query all the four using JOIN, is it ok?

Comment: Yes you have to use JOIN in order to retrieve your comments and the entities. The reason is because you have several comments from several users per entity and it is not recommended to store all the comments in the same entity record using a Blob field because your RDBMS is going to become slower as soon that you have a considerable number of comments per row.

Comment: Separate tables are good for entity type specific data, but if this does not usually come with a comment, there might be wasted text columns, which take up space, because some of them are being used. The specific tables will become unnecessarily heavy. DB normalization is about splitting data into unique, logical units and the opposite of cramming everything into few tables (here: entity specific and global comment data together). If a central comments table is indexed properly, there will not be much of advantage through four different tables.

Comment: I strongly recommend not to use joins at all, when working with heavy text columns! Joins will create a cartesian product of the results ( not to be confused with cross join CP when forgetting ON). That means, for every row of appendix data (comments or other), the article/paragraph/block nvarchar(max) content will be duplicated! Better make separate selects on the subsequent tables with comments and possibly other appended data!

Answer (score 1):

The content tables will be dynamic, too, because content can be added, modified or deleted.

I would create a single comments table with only the primary key and the comment data (text as nvarchar(max) data type, Foreign key to Author).

Then, for each content table, a reference table, containing PKs from the content and comment table as a pair of foreign keys. Theoretically, the comment could belong to multiple content items, something that should be prevented in the application (a unique constraint on the Comment FK reference could limit at least to one parent per content type).

Don't forget proper indices on the content, comment and reference tables

Comment: Let's assume that each comment is unique, is it still efficient to hold a linking table for each entity, this table will hold the dynamic data that refers to its source, and one comment table that similar to all entities? similar by its columns.

Comment: The linking tables are required for referencing a central comments table. If you decide to create separate comments tables, as in Juan Lago's proposal, you can simply use a foreign key, referencing the content entity. Just avoid non-FK polymorphic references (Id "1234" in "Paragraphs" or Id "567" in "Articles"). Basically, a linking table only contains links. You can instead make "child" tables for each entity type, with entity specific data, and from there, reference a (central table) comment, if available. This child table should then have a PK on it's own.